# JDBC read driver taking too long to extract dataframe from JDA database

Tags: python, jdbc, aws-glue

I am trying to read dataframe from a JDA database and printing the logs on rapid7. I have defined a function to read the dataframe and return the extracted dataframe.

```
def fetch_data_from_db(jdaConnectionProperties, jdaCredentials, configData):
    global tidalJobStatus
    driverName = jdaConnectionProperties['JDBC_DRIVER_CLASS_NAME']
    url = jdaConnectionProperties['JDBC_CONNECTION_URL']
    hostName = configData['jda']['host']
    serviceName = configData['jda']['servicename']
    schemaName = configData['jda']['schema']
    dbUser = jdaCredentials['username']
    dbPassword = jdaCredentials['password']
    tableName = "BillingTable"
    
    try:
        sparkDataFrame = sparkSession.read.format('jdbc')\
                 .option('driver', driverName)\
                 .option('url', url)\
                 .option('dbtable', f'{schemaName}.{tableName}')\
                 .option('user', dbUser)\
                 .option('password', dbPassword)\
                 .load()
        log.info("dataframe fetched")
        log.info("count: " + str(sparkDataFrame.count()))
    except:
        log.exception(transactionId + "Failed to fetch records from table: " + tableName)
        raise
    
    return sparkDataFrame
```

In the above snippet I am logging the record count in rapid7 but the last log I see is,

```
log.info("dataframe fetched")
```

And nothing after that. The AWS job has been running for 45 minutes now whereas it should have been successfully ran within 7 minutes.

I have checked the connection details and they are all correct.

I tried checking the connection properties and ran for another table and it worked fine. It is not running for this one.

Comment: I suspect that your issue is something having to do with latency or perhaps a transaction creating a rollback table.  I'm not sure how you came up with your 7 minute benchmark.  You need to know more about the details of how the read method works.